# Perl atan2 values out of range

Tags: perl

I'm trying to compute the angle of an AB Segment with the horizontal axis using the atan2() in Perl. The Perl documantation says

> atan2 Y,X
>   Returns the arctangent of Y/X in the range -PI to PI.

The following subroutine:

```
sub computeAngle($$$$){
my($x1_, $y1_, $x2_, $y2_) = @_;
$result  = 0;

$result = atan2($y2_-$y1_, $x2_-$x1_)*360/3.14159265359;

print " Angle= $result°\n";
return $result;
}
```

Produces values outside of the interval:

0 0 -30.7933862796053 216.100103110075  Angle= 196.219639131902°

0 0 -81.245545537211 -11.7299860790372  Angle= -343.569155014717°

Why is this happening?

Comment: When you're converting radians into degrees you should multiply by 180, not 360: `...* 180 / 3.14159265359`;

Comment: you are definetely right Dmitry. Please answer the question so as I can rate it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You conversion is incorrect; you should multiply by **180**, not **360**:

```
$result = atan2($y2_-$y1_, $x2_-$x1_)*180/3.14159265359;
```